# Android app with plyer won't launch. Am I missing somethng?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I wanted to try out plyer and wrote an Android app. The problem is that it won't run on my phone. The app starts loading but then immediately closes.

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import flash
from kivy.utils import platform

if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA,
                         Permission.FLASHLIGHT])

class Light(BoxLayout):

    def an():
        flash.on()

    def aus():
        flash.off()



kv = Builder.load_file("light.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

And this is the light.kv file:

```
<Light>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:3

        Button:
            id:a
            text:"an"
            on_release: root.an
        Button:
            id:b
            text:"aus"
            on_release: root.aus
```

That's what I did in the buildozer.spec file:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy, android, plyer

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, CAMERA, FLASHLIGHT, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I'm using python 3.8.5, plyer 2.0.0, buildozer 1.2.0, kivy 2.0.0rc3.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a class called `MyMainApp`, then are calling a method called `run` which doesn’t exit in that class, make sure to define a run method.

```
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

    def run(self):
        # your code here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: um , I don't think so. because the `MyMainApp` is inheritance with the `kivy.app.App` class which got the function `run()`

Answer (score 0):

remove the permissions from buildozer.spec file

android.permissions = INTERNET, CAMERA, FLASHLIGHT, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE